# find objects in a database by range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to find objects in a database, but i can't get it to work if i use range as a query. 
Does anyone have any pointer of how i can find documents between to date values?

if I skip the range i get all the document in the database so something is wrong with the query,

mondodb query

```
     db.collection('insights').find({'date': {$gt: '10000000', $lt: '90000000000000'}}).toArray(function (err, items){
    res.json(items);
    console.log(items)
});
```

database

```
{"_id":"5450b2889d96472e67c99691","username":"josef","date":"'1414574728436'"}
```

Comment: Your `date` value in the doc is a string containing embedded `'` characters.  Change your dates to be an actual Date or numeric type.

Comment: @JohnnyHK is right ,, change your date type into Number if you are search with range condition